# swift: slide in certain area to segue

Tags: view, segue, swipe, gesture

I want to have a certain area of my mainViewContoller (mid of screen) where you can swipe left to go to another view. So I want it to work like a page view controller, but only in a certain area of the screen. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. add a container view in your mainViewController
2. embed any view controller's view as container view's root view. If you want it to be a page view, set a page view controller's view as the root view.